# What's the best way to merge to arrays based on key values in each array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have these two arrays that I am currently using two loops to merge. I was wondering if there was a better way to merge these arrays:

```
$args = array(
  'Name' => 'Test Name', 
  'Email' => 'root@localhost.com', 
  'Message' => 'There is no place like 127.0.0.1!'
);

$fields = array(
  2 => array(
    'label' => 'Name',
    'id' => 2
  ),
  3 => array(
    'label' => 'Email',
    'id' => 3
  ),
  4 => array(
    'label' => 'Message',
    'id' => 4
  )
);
```

I am trying to merge them into an array like this:

```
$merged = array(
  2 => array(
    'label' => 'Name',
    'id' => 2,
    'value' => 'Test Name'
  ),
  3 => array(
    'label' => 'Email',
    'id' => 3,
    'value' => 'root@localhost.com'
  ),
  4 => array(
    'label' => 'Message',
    'id' => 4,
    'value' => 'There is no place like 127.0.0.1!'
  )
);
```

I am currently using this dual foreach loop to do it:

```
foreach ( $args['fields'] as $k => $v ) {
        foreach( $fields['fields'] as $i => $item ) {
            if ( $item['label'] === $k ) {
                $fields['fields'][$i]['value'] = $v;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried using `array_merge` and `array_merge_recurisve`, but it throws off the array keys from the `$fields` array.

Any thoughts or better approaches to try and achieve my desired outcome?

Comment: What's wrong with the method you are already using?

Comment: I agree the method you are using is going to be the most efficient ..  Just in case keys get mixed up etc etc .. IMO you're already doing it the "right way"

Comment: The actual `$fields` array has many more values to it, and it just seemed inefficient to have to loop through them all just to find a single field to match on.

Comment: @zeropsi PHP is _fast_. If you aren't looping over hundreds of thousands of rows, you're probably going to be fine.

Comment: Thanks @GrumpyCrouton - while I hope I am never going to have that many rows to loop through, there is a good chance that there could be thousands. I think for good measure, and just to ensure some added logic, I am going to add a `break` to the code so it spins out the inner `foreach` once it has matched up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need nested loops. Just loop over the `$fields` array, and then access the corresponding entry in `$args` with an index.

```
$merged = []
foreach ($fields as $key => &field) {
    $field['value'] = $args[$field['label']];
    $merged[$key] = $field;
}
```